# SHA1 hash for OSX 10.10 Yosemite public release?

Tags: macos

I have a less-than-reliable internet connection, so my download of Yosemite over the App Store has been broken over several tries. I would like to know if my download is intact. If you can run this command in Terminal:

```
shasum /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ Yosemite.app/Contents/SharedSupport/InstallESD.dmg
```

and share your result. This way we can agree on what a clean copy looks like.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I run your request and here is the result.

```
eebf02a20ac27665a966957eec6f5e6fe3228a19  /Applications/Install OS X Yosemite.app/Contents/SharedSupport/InstallESD.dmg
```

And for Yosemite 10.10.1 the shasum is:

```
a673c2c6d967f4da2934b7d6cf3736936970b194
```

Please wait about a minute or two for Terminal to get the number.

Comment: Thanks. I will be able to collaborate that in "6 hours 43 minutes", then I will check the answer.

Comment: Yep. This is the same result for me.

Comment: what does it mean if i got a different result? i got this: >059f2603a91465bcee24c864d446da30df920f85 /Applications/Install OS X Yosemite.app/Contents/SharedSupport/InstallESD.dmg

Comment: @Amanda Which Yosemite are you trying to use (Version ?)

Comment: @Buscar웃 I'm using Yosemite on MacPro 2011

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post once you have sufficient [reputation](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Comment: For reference: I just downloaded Yosemite 10.10.5 from the Mac App Store and the SHA1 hash for InstallESD.dmg is ef5cc8851b893dbe4bc9a5cf5c648c10450af6bc.

Comment: @djule5 for the installer downloaded today, [I get a different result](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/246331/8546); would you like to reverify yours? For the .app that contains the image, what is the version and build?

Comment: @Amanda thank you for drawing attention to the discrepancy. It led to revision of the answer.

Comment: @GrahamPerrin I don't have the file/app available anymore so I can't verify, but other references point to the same hash I posted earlier, e.g. https://github.com/drduh/OS-X-Security-and-Privacy-Guide/blob/master/InstallESD_Hashes.csv

Answer (score 8):

Why not check the signature instead?  That way, you won't have to rely on an external checksum.

Here's an example of this done with a Mavericks installer (I don't have the Yosemite installer yet):

```
$ codesign -dvvv Install\ OS\ X\ Mavericks.app/
Executable=…/Install OS X Mavericks.app/Contents/MacOS/Install OS X Mavericks
Identifier=com.apple.InstallAssistant.Mavericks
Format=bundle with Mach-O thin (x86_64)
CodeDirectory v=20100 size=285 flags=0x200(kill) hashes=7+3 location=embedded
Hash type=sha1 size=20
CDHash=9bf12663fe5f73d2780eb2badc2fe7a86a2c7164
Signature size=4169
Authority=Apple Mac OS Application Signing
Authority=Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority
Authority=Apple Root CA
Info.plist entries=30
TeamIdentifier=not set
Sealed Resources version=1 rules=14 files=80
Internal requirements count=1 size=124
```

Comment: So... how does the signature help me check the integrity of the download? Can you elaborate?

Comment: A digital signature is a way to verify that a file hasn't been tampered with or is corrupted, and will become invalid if it is. A digital signature is based on cryptography and is designed to be very hard to fake.

Comment: How would you tell if it's invalid? I ran this command on the OS X Yosemite installer, then tried adding a file to the .app directory, and also tried modifying version.plist, and the output of this command did not change.

Comment: @HenrikN that should be a great question; if you find it (or [make it, yourself](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/asking)) please share a link.

Comment: @GrahamPerrin This was two years ago, so I'm not motivated to do so, but go for it if you like :)

Answer (score 1):

Complementing [the accepted answer for 10.10](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/150908/8546) …

---

### 10.10.1

Version 1.6.7 (1014) of *Install OS X Yosemite.app*

a673c2c6d967f4da2934b7d6cf3736936970b194

---

### 10.10.2

Version 1.6.10 (1017) of the app

059f2603a91465bcee24c864d446da30df920f85

Please note, that differs from [revision 2 of the accepted answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/revisions/150908/2); the result added to that revision was truly for 10.10.*1*.

---

### 10.10.3

Version 1.6.16 (1023) of the app

dc4d4d0a7cd4aea4514025d23a58d05107369fa9

---

### 10.10.5

Version 1.6.43 (1043) of the app, downloaded from App Store first on Sunday 2016-07-17, again on 2016-07-18

0e063fd87d5b0a4f68dbd35da95b2018748f88eb

At https://github.com/drduh/OS-X-Security-and-Privacy-Guide/blob/master/InstallESD_Hashes.csv and [from commentary under the accepted answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/150896/sha1-hash-for-osx-10-10-yosemite-public-release/150908#comment250867_150908):

ef5cc8851b893dbe4bc9a5cf5c648c10450af6bc

Concerning the discrepancy: https://github.com/drduh/OS-X-Security-and-Privacy-Guide/issues/125

---

### Records of my checks for .5

```
Mashemite:Desktop grahamperrin$ cd /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ Yosemite.app/Contents/SharedSupport/
Mashemite:SharedSupport grahamperrin$ shasum InstallESD.dmg
0e063fd87d5b0a4f68dbd35da95b2018748f88eb  InstallESD.dmg
Mashemite:SharedSupport grahamperrin$ sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.12
BuildVersion:   16A239m
Mashemite:SharedSupport grahamperrin$
```

– and with reference to [Mac OS X: How to verify a SHA-1 digest - Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/HT201259):

```
Mashemite:SharedSupport grahamperrin$ openssl sha1 InstallESD.dmg 
SHA1(InstallESD.dmg)= 0e063fd87d5b0a4f68dbd35da95b2018748f88eb
Mashemite:SharedSupport grahamperrin$
```

### The record of my checks for .3, .2 and .1

```
$ sudo zfs mount
zhandy                          /Volumes/zhandy
$ pwd
/Volumes/zhandy/chronological/OS X/10/10/3/1.6.16 (1023)/Install OS X Yosemite.app/Contents/SharedSupport
$ time shasum InstallESD.dmg
dc4d4d0a7cd4aea4514025d23a58d05107369fa9  InstallESD.dmg
13.47user 2.21system 4:25.25elapsed 5%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 6864maxresident)k
11084834inputs+0outputs (0major+762minor)pagefaults 0swaps
$ cd /Volumes/zhandy/chronological/OS\ X/10/10/2/1.6.10\ \(1017\)/Install\ OS\ X\ Yosemite.app/Contents/SharedSupport/
$ time shasum InstallESD.dmg
059f2603a91465bcee24c864d446da30df920f85  InstallESD.dmg
12.66user 2.03system 3:52.58elapsed 6%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 6732maxresident)k
10182180inputs+0outputs (0major+760minor)pagefaults 0swaps
$ cd /Volumes/zhandy/chronological/OS\ X/10/10/1/1.6.7\ \(1014\)/Install\ OS\ X\ Yosemite.app/Contents/SharedSupport/
$ time shasum InstallESD.dmg
a673c2c6d967f4da2934b7d6cf3736936970b194  InstallESD.dmg
12.39user 1.95system 3:36.28elapsed 6%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 6804maxresident)k
10159544inputs+0outputs (0major+762minor)pagefaults 0swaps
$ sudo zpool status
[sudo] password for grahamperrin: 
  pool: zhandy
 state: ONLINE
status: The pool is formatted using a legacy on-disk format.  The pool can
        still be used, but some features are unavailable.
action: Upgrade the pool using 'zpool upgrade'.  Once this is done, the
        pool will no longer be accessible on software that does not support
        feature flags.
  scan: scrub in progress since Sun Jul 17 19:22:15 2016
    26.9G scanned out of 513G at 15.7M/s, 8h50m to go
    0 repaired, 5.25% done
config:

        NAME                                        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        zhandy                                      ONLINE       0     0     0
          ata-SAMSUNG_HM641JI_S2HUJ9FBA00492-part2  ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
$ date ; uname -a
Sun 17 Jul 20:05:10 BST 2016
Linux momh167-gjp4-kubuntu-hpelitebook850g2 4.4.0-31-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 13 00:07:12 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$
```

### Certainty that the checksummed data for .3, .2 and .1 has not changed since it was written to my disk

```
$ date ; sudo zpool status
Mon 18 Jul 04:29:41 BST 2016
[sudo] password for grahamperrin: 
  pool: zhandy
 state: ONLINE
status: The pool is formatted using a legacy on-disk format.  The pool can
        still be used, but some features are unavailable.
action: Upgrade the pool using 'zpool upgrade'.  Once this is done, the
        pool will no longer be accessible on software that does not support
        feature flags.
  scan: scrub repaired 0 in 7h43m with 0 errors on Mon Jul 18 03:05:25 2016
config:

        NAME                                        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        zhandy                                      ONLINE       0     0     0
          ata-SAMSUNG_HM641JI_S2HUJ9FBA00492-part2  ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
$
```

### Confirming that the version of the app for 10.10.1 was 1.6.7

```
$ cd /Volumes/zhandy/chronological/OS\ X/10/10/1/1.6.7\ \(1014\)/Install\ OS\ X\ Yosemite.app/Contents/
$ cat version.plist
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>BuildAliasOf</key>
        <string>InstallAssistant</string>
        <key>BuildVersion</key>
        <string>286</string>
        <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
        <string>1.6.7</string>
        <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
        <string>1014</string>
        <key>ProjectName</key>
        <string>InstallAssistant_MAS</string>
        <key>SourceVersion</key>
        <string>532000000000000</string>
</dict>
</plist>
$
```

---

For 10.10.4, I never downloaded the installer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use apple's digital signature check , as shown here 
https://support.apple.com/en-ap/HT202369

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.