# How to get OSX Yosemite outside the Mac App Store

Tags: macos, mac-appstore, build-version

I have the following scenario.

- At work I run an Ubuntu PC machine with fast connection.
- At home I have a Mac without any kind of outside connection (offline)

My question is how do I get the OSX Yosemite offline installer to install it on my home Mac, obviously I can't access the Mac App Store in my Ubuntu machine at work. Is there any way that I can get a direct link for an offline installer ?

Note:

- In previous versions I get the ESD dmg file that contains everything that I need to install. But I can't find any kind of that link with Yosemite. All of the current ones redirects to the Mac App Store.
- I need the final version released yesterday, Betas or GM aren't an option

Comment: go to nearest apple store and get it there.

Comment: near ? i wish that i could have an apple store here in my country. :)

Comment: you could get it from my Google drive, but I wont do that to strangers :) So what is the problem with Mac and Internet ? or find a friend who can download it for you on his mac.

Comment: yeah, sounds fair. Guess that i will wait for a friend to download it or find third party stuff

Comment: The installer which downloads to the Applications folder will disappear once Run. I would make sure that before your friend runs the installer they either make a copy of it somewhere else or make a copy by zipping it it first.

Comment: I find a mistake in my answer. After extensive research, I decide to retract it. Please de-accept it.

Answer (score 2):

It's on usenet already & no doubt torrents [though I don't go there]
The Release build is 14A389

> the release version of Yosemite is build 14A389—the last developer seed was build 14a388, also known as GMC3. The last public beta version was build 14A388b. That makes the MAS release newer than all other released builds

Up to you, of course, to decide whether you trust the source.

[SHA1 hash for OSX 10.10 Yosemite public release?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/150896/sha1-hash-for-osx-10-10-yosemite-public-release) Has the SHA1 so you can check whichever version you get...

Extract...
run this command in Terminal:

```
shasum /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ Yosemite.app/Contents/SharedSupport/InstallESD.dmg
```

response should be

```
eebf02a20ac27665a966957eec6f5e6fe3228a19  /Applications/Install OS X Yosemite.app/Contents/SharedSupport/InstallESD.dmg
```

Comment: At final i'm using a torrent. I'll check the shasum later to check if match. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: For reference: I just downloaded Yosemite 10.10.5 from the Mac App Store and the SHA1 hash for InstallESD.dmg is ef5cc8851b893dbe4bc9a5cf5c648c10450af6bc.

Comment: @djule5 for the installer downloaded today, [I get a different result](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/246331/8546); would you like to reverify yours? For the .app that contains the image, what is the version and build?

Answer (score 0):

No, I had a look and it seems that there is no way without using the app store. You will either have to go through some third party stuff or get an active internet connection on your mac.