# Downloading older versions of OSX from a store

Tags: macos, install, mac-pro

I am having an old Mac Pro (I think it is mid or late 2007), which is actually not capable of running latest OS X nor latest Xcode... Still, it is pretty much fast ( dual core 2.66 GHz, 8 GB ram, 400GB hard-disk ...) for some other tasks. For example, it is perfect for running Android Studio on it...

But, currently I don't have an OS X installed on it. So I am trying to make a bootable USB with ideally OSX Yosemite installed on it. But there is no Yosemite available to download anymore (nor for example Mavericks).

I have found [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/151137/how-to-get-osx-yosemite-outside-the-mac-app-store) and there is a statement that if we have a paid apple developer account, we will be able to download older OS X versions. Still, even if I have a paid developer account for iOS development, I can't find nothing except Yosemite updates and combo updates.

Also I have tried to install Lion which coming along with Mac, but that didn't worked. I get message saying:

> Item temporarily unavailable

So, currently, I can't get this machine running anyhow.

Is there are way to download a Yosemite or Mavericks from a Store ? I don't know if the answers from above are outdated, or this is not possible ?